# Best way to use JPA with relationships

Tags: java, jsf, jpa, netbeans, ejb

When I have an Entity with relationships I don't know which is the best way to save changes to DB.

Here is a simplified entity. Please consider I have made little changes to the code to post it here and I can have introduced some errors.

```
public class Permessitemporanei implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID_permesso")
    private Integer iDpermesso;
    @Column(name = "Stato_permesso")
    private Integer statopermesso;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "iDpermesso")
    private Collection<Accessiconpermesso> accessiconpermessoCollection;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "iDpermesso")
    private Ingressiconpermesso  ingressiconpermesso;
```

As you can see it is linked to other 2 entities with a OneToMany and OneToOne relationships.
I'm using Glassfish with jta so transactions and entityManagers are managed by the container.

At a time I have a detached (JPA terminology) Permessitemporanei instance in memory.
I have to persist the following changes to the database:
1- the associated ingressiconpermesso must be deleted
2- a new ingressiconpermesso must be created
3- statopermesso field must be updated
4- a new Accessiconpermesso must be added to the collection accessiconpermessoCollection

Which is the best way of doing so ? Perhaps I can do all necessary changes in the Permessitemporanei instance an merge it but I had many troubles doing so and start to think it is not the right side of the relationships to persist changes.
For me it more natural to save an object at a time, so eliminating all those cascade = CascadeType.ALL.

Suppose my Permessitemporanei instance is called 'permesso' ; my code is something like this:

1. getEntityManager().remove(permesso.ingressiconpermesso);
2. getEntityManager().persist(a new Ingressiconpermesso );
3. getEntityManager().merge(permesso) // once its statopermesso field has been updated;
4. getEntityManager().perist(a new Accessiconpermesso );

Obviously this way I have to manually update the in memory 'permesso' with all the changes I made on Database.

Is there a better approach ?

By the way all the JPA relationships I have seen are bidirectional. Can I make them unidirectional ? To put it in other words can I safely eliminate
Code:

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "iDpermesso")
    private Collection accessiconpermessoCollection;

from the Permessitemporanei entity preserving it on the Accessiconpermesso entity or do i break JPA ?

Thanks
Filippo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I like to approach complex entity updates is to:

1. Start a new transaction.
2. Make all the changes that I want to make against my Objects in memory.
3. Tell the `EntityManager` what I did once I'm done.
4. Commit the transaction.

But first things first, you will likely have a much easier time of things if you get a non-detached `Permessitemporanei` instance to start with:

```
Permessitemporanei persistentInstance = em.find(Permessitemporanei.class, detachedInstance.getId());
```

Then do all of your changes in memory, inform the `EntityManager`, and commit the transaction:

```
//begin a transaction
em.getTransaction().begin();

//remember the old Ingressiconpermesso instance
Ingressiconpermesso oldIngression = persistentInstance.getIngressiconpermesso();

//create a new Ingressiconpermesso instance
Ingressiconpermesso newIngression = new Ingressiconpermesso();
//call newIngression.set...() methods here

//associate the new Ingressiconpermesso with the Permessitemporanei 
persistentInstance.setIngressiconpermesso(newIngression);

//update statopermesso
persistentInstance.setStatopermesso(7); //replace '7' with whatever the real value is

//add a new Accessiconpermesso
Accessiconpermesso accession = new Accessiconpermesso();
//call accession.set...() methods here

//associate the Accessiconpermesso with the Permessitemporanei
accession.setPermissitemporanei(persistentInstance);

//now tell the EntityManager what we did
em.remove(oldIngression);        //delete the old Ingressiconpermesso 
em.persist(newIngression);       //add the new Ingressiconpermesso 
em.persist(accession);           //add the Accessiconpermesso
em.merge(persistentInstance);    //update the Permessitemporanei

//commit the transaction
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

To answer your other question, no, you generally do not need to annotate both sides of a relationship.  You can remove your `@OneToMany` annotation if you want, and it shouldn't break anything (as far as JPA cares, anyways...you may well have application code that relies upon this `Collection` being present and properly populated, and removing the JPA mapping will of course break any such code).  However, I don't really think you gain anything by removing it, so I'd recommend leaving it alone.

Comment: Thank you very much Aroth, also because you spent time writing code for a better understanding. I would need a bit more help. First of all a trivial question. I suppose you forgot to update the accessiconpermessoCollection in memory, didn't you ?

Comment: Secondly you make remove/persist/merge operation on all the objects. I suppose this implies you are not using cascade.. and it is the way I fill more comfortable with too.

Comment: Again on the oneToMany relationship related to a foreign key on DB. If I'm not interested in maintaining object consistency in memory because I plan to refresh/reload them, do I still need to to write `persistentInstance.getAccessiconpermessoCollection.add(accession)`  from my first question ? Does JPA complains when I merge persistentInstance if its collection is not updated ?

Comment: @Filippo - Updating the accessiconpermesso Collection in memory is optional.  As long as the new accessiconpermesso instance is persisted and the Permessitemporanei is merged then the in-memory Collection should be automatically updated by the `EntityManager`.  And yes, in general the only thing I rely on cascade for is delete.  For other operations I always explicitly state my desired intent.  I think it leads to clearer code.  And no, you shouldn't need to call `persistentInstance.getAccessiconpermessoCollection.add(accession)`,as I mentioned.  JPA should do this for you, without complaint.